# How to move markdown button from the top to the bottom of the cell in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio for MacOS, Version: 1.50.1

This markdown button (circled in red) on the top of the cell takes a lot of space and visually distracts me from code. It is on the top of the cell as shown here:

[image]

However, on the internet I find the screenshots with markdown button on the bottom of the cell:

[image]

How to move it to the bottom of the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the VS Code Python extension. With the update 2019.11.49689, the Markdown icon in Jupiter notebook cell was moved to the upper left corner. Prior to 2019.10.44104 version, the layout of the cell included the Markdown button on the left side of the cell, as shown in the question above.

I have filed it with the [Python extension repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python). Feature request: There has to be at least a described way how the user can move the Markdown icon away from the upper left corner of the cell.